# Ghost exorcisms of fields?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, terminology, conformal-field-theory, ghosts

In Mack's paper ["D-independent representation of Conformal Field Theories in D dimensions via transformation to auxiliary Dual Resonance Models. Scalar amplitudes"](https://arxiv.org/abs/0907.2407), he makes the following statement regarding fundamental fields:

> Fundamental fields play a special role in the Euclidean partial wave expansion, requiring exorcision of a ghost - the shadow pole of [Ferrara, Gatto, Grillo, and Parisi](http://inspirehep.net/record/77568/).

I have never heard of ghost "exorcisions" (exorcisms?). Presumably they refer to some sort of removal of the ghost contributions to a theory? Or is this a joke? I'm very confused.

Answer (score 0):

It’s a misspelling of “exorcism” by a German writer, just like the nearby adjective “Euklidean”. (I‘m presuming the writer is German based on the institution.) It’s just a fun way of saying “removal” of the ghost.

Comment: Or perhaps a play on excision.